# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient Requests not consistent

Tags: c#, servicestack

I've created a `ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient` to consume 3rd party API.

I'm using the `Get(IReturn<MyType>)` method.

My Request object looks like this:

```
public class MyRequest : Base, IReturn<MyType>
{
    public MyRequest(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        Date = dateTime.Date;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; init; }
}
```

And normally everything is fine but sometimes it fails to get results.

I set `ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient.CaptureHttp()` and reviewed the logs and what I found was that it's failing when `Date` is converted to a `long` rather than a `string` in this format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I'm thinking it's probably my fault.  I probably set a static setting that toggles this behavior somewhere in my solution but I don't remember and I'm not finding it.

My question is really just why is this happening.

I already have a solution and that is to modify `MyRequest` slightly as follows:

```
public class MyRequest : Base, IReturn<MyType>
{
    public MyRequest(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        Date = $"{dateTime.Date:yyyy-MM-dd}";
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "date")]
    public string Date { get; init; }
}
```

but again, why was this required and what could possibly be causing it to work for some time and then change behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Date Serialization the ServiceStack's Serializers return Date's in WCF's Date serialization format, here's some [parsing examples](https://docs.servicestack.net/json-format#parsing-json-dates). You can also configure it to use a [different Date format](https://docs.servicestack.net/json-format#datehandler-dh), e.g:

```
JsConfig.Init(new Config {
    DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601,
});
```

Please note you should never put any implementation logic inside DTOs, they should be impl-free classes used as inert Data Transfer Objects (DTO) only.

All DTOs should also have a parameterless constructor which are used by serializers to rehydrate DTOs during deserialization.

If you want to add impl logic in a class put it in a separate domain model that you map to a plain DTO that is returned from your API instead.